# Create a month column based on period

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm a financial analysis for a mobbile company, and recently I started to used Power BI to create dashboard for tracking user behavior. I have a question about writing DAX to create a month column to present a relationship between the number of period  which customer top up their account and the real month. For example:
Period Table (https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLB8w.png)

This table show the relationship between period and month. The first period for this month is March 2023, the second is February 2023 and so on ( since I create the report in the begining of next month). I want the month column will automatically change to April 2023 for the next month for the first period and March 2023 for the second and so on.

I'm thinking of using SWITCH and TODAY() DAX function, but it might too long and a bit complicated when the period in fact might raise to 3x or 4x.

Please give me a solution for my question. Thank you so much.

Regards,

.

Answer (score 0):

formula as below:

```
Month = format(date(year(today()),month(today())-[Period],1),"mmm-yy")
```

[image]